# Extract values from payload of SENSOR DHT22 connected to Sonoff Tasmota

Tags: python, json, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using Sonoff basic flashed with Tasmora firmware. I connected a temp sensor DHT22. On this device is setup MQTT to send sensor values to Mosquitto, which is installed on a Linux pc.

The data I am getting is in the format:

```
 mosquitto_sub -h my.dns.xxx -p 81111 -v -u user -P pass -t channels/sonoff/SENSOR/#

channels/sonoff/SENSOR {"Time":"2018-07-07T03:55:13","AM2301":{"Temperature":25.0,"Humidity":62.4},"TempUnit":"C"}
channels/sonoff/SENSOR {"Time":"2018-07-07T03:55:23","AM2301":{"Temperature":25.0,"Humidity":62.4},"TempUnit":"C"}
channels/sonoff/SENSOR {"Time":"2018-07-07T03:55:33","AM2301":{"Temperature":25.0,"Humidity":62.5},"TempUnit":"C"}
channels/sonoff/SENSOR {"Time":"2018-07-07T03:55:43","AM2301":{"Temperature":25.0,"Humidity":62.5},"TempUnit":"C"}
channels/sonoff/SENSOR {"Time":"2018-07-07T03:55:53","AM2301":{"Temperature":25.0,"Humidity":62.6},"TempUnit":"C"}
```

I need Python code which will publish the values of temperature and humidity, which will be published on thingspeak.com.

I already have some Python code for publishing but it is for an OrangePI board where values are read in a different way:

```
import dht22
import time
import datetime
import os



PIN2 = port.PA6
gpio.init()
n=75 #after every 150 (~10 minutes) load (connect to thingspeak) again!
i=0

channelId = "xxxxxx"         # Put your channel ID here,i.e.. the number from the URL, https://thingspeak.com/channels/285697
apiKey = "xxxxxxxxx"  # Put the API key here (the Write API Key from the API Keys tab in ThingSpeak)
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("mqtt.thingspeak.com",1883,60)


instance = dht22.DHT22(pin=PIN2)
os.system('clear')

while True:
    result = instance.read()
    if result.is_valid():
        i=i+1
        print 'I after increment is: ', i
        print 'VALID and i is:',i
        print("\033[37;1mLast valid input: \033[0m" + "\033[33;1m" + str(strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", gmtime())) + "\033[0m")
        print("\033[37;1mTemperature: \033[1;31m%.2f C\033[0m" % result.temperature)
        print("\033[37;1mHumidity: \033[32;1m%.2f %%\033[0m\n" % result.humidity)
        if i == n-1:
            print 'I is: ', i
            print 'Now setting value i to zero\nLoading libary again'
            i=0
            print 'I after setting to zero is: ', i
            client = mqtt.Client()
            client.connect("mqtt.thingspeak.com",1883,60)
            client.publish("channels/%s/publish/%s" % (channelId,apiKey), "field1=" + str(result.temperature) + "&field2=" + str(result.humidity))
        else:
            client.publish("channels/%s/publish/%s" % (channelId,apiKey), "field1=" + str(result.temperature) + "&field2=" + str(result.humidity))
    else:
        print 'WE HAVE INVALID and i is:',i 
        time.sleep(4)
```

I'm pretty sure that it is very similar to what I am searching for, but I'm not able to write the code.

Can someone help me with this few lines of code?

Comment: The largest mistake you are doing is to try to open the DHT22 sensor. It is not on the machine you are working on but on your IoT device. You have to listen to one MQTT broker, maybe process the received messages and publish it to the other broker.

Comment: OK, I know..how can I do that?

Comment: Basically, you read [some docs](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/), write some code and ask a new question on SO when you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've misunderstood what MQTT is. There's a very useful reference on the [ThingsSpeak](https://au.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/mqtt-basics.html) site, and there's probably even better references in your native language.

Note in particular that MQTT always requires a single *broker* and one or more *clients*. Clients may *subscribe* or *publish* to a topic. The broker will receive any *publish* messages from a client and send them to all the clients that have *subscribed*.

In your case you have a Sonoff basic (which, incidentally, looks nothing like what you describe - you must have modified it extensively?) which is acting as a MQTT **client**. Your Linux PC is acting as a **broker** and you're also running a **client** on the PC (though the `my.dns.xxx` suggests there's some sort of virtual network involved too). You then want to connect to ThingsSpeak, which is also a **broker**. Brokers don't talk to brokers so what you're trying to do wont work.

If you want to stick with what you've got (and not simply change the Sonoff basic to be client of ThingsSpeak, rather than the PC, for example) then what you need is a **MQTT Bridge**. A bridge allows you to connect two brokers. A bridge is essentially a client that subscribes to one broker and publishes everything to another broker.

Comment: The scenario is next:
Sonoff sending data to Mosquitto what is installed on Linux. On Linux I can use commands mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub. What I want is to send , let it say, forward those two values (temp, and humidity) with python code to thingspeak to have a graph.I do not understand why u say that it is not posible. It just need to be read and send it.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the setup of the asker. He has a broker on a linux machine and the Sonoff, which is basically an ESP8266, acts as an MQTT client publishing messages.

Comment: Exactlly Klaus..
Thx for clarification!

Comment: Oh my mistake, the "my.dns.xxx" threw me. I've corrected the answer. You still have the fundamental issue of two brokers, so the answer of using a bridge (or bypassing the Linux broker) still stands. You can write the bridge in Python if you wish.

Comment: Yes I would like to write the bridge in python if I would be able to type it. Thats why I asking the help of community!

Comment: If we speaking of bridhe for mqtt I found a project on Githun with name: Mqspeak
https://github.com/mqopen/mqspeak
This project really working but only problem is that he announcing in form as he read from my topic qith {"..."} form and not just those two value what I need.

Comment: @easyyu it sounds like you're asking someone to write code for you. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You could try Upwork or Freelancer, or if you want to continue to get help from the SO community, mark this answer as helpful and ask a new, more specific question about the code you're trying to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at the end I understood the basic of Python..and I made a script.
It looks like:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt, time, sys
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

last_topic = ""
lasy_payload = ""

channelId = "xxxxxxx"         # Put your channel ID here,i.e.. the number from the URL, https://thingspeak.com/channels/285697
apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  # Put the API key here (the Write API Key from the API Keys tab in ThingSpeak)
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("mqtt.thingspeak.com",1883,60)

# main
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected...\n")
    client.is_connected = True

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    ''' note: message is a tuple of (topic, payload, qos, retain)'''
    global last_topic, last_payload
    last_topic = message.topic
    last_payload = message.payload
    print("Message with topic: [" + last_topic + "] and payload [" + last_payload + "]")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.is_connected = False
client.loop_start()
client.connect("localhost")

time.sleep(4)
if not client.is_connected:
    print("problem connecting to the MQTT server; please check your settings")
    sys.exit(1)

# ask for system status
time.sleep(1)
client.subscribe("channels/sonoff/SENSOR")
client.publish("cmnd/channels/sonoff/status",None)

# now wait for a time stamp from the sonoff; this could take an hour
client.subscribe("channels/sonoff/SENSOR")

while 1:
    if last_topic.startswith("channels/sonoff") and last_topic.endswith("SENSOR"):
        Payload_Temp = last_payload.find('"Temperature":')
        Payload_Hum = last_payload.find('"Humidity":')
        Temp = last_payload[Payload_Temp+14:Payload_Temp+14+4]
        Hum = last_payload[Payload_Hum+11:Payload_Hum+11+4]
        print("Temperature is: "+Temp +"C")
        print("Humidity is: "+Hum +"%")
        print("")
        client = mqtt.Client()
        client.connect("mqtt.thingspeak.com",1883,60)
        client.publish("channels/%s/publish/%s" % (channelId,apiKey), "field1=" + str(Temp) + "&field2=" + str(Hum))    
#        break
    time.sleep(32)# Couse Thingspeak accept only every 15 sec new value!

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

It sending data every ~32second to Thingspeak!
Working perfectly!